# some bootstrap columns overlap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I'm using flex-column and divided the page into two sections so that when the page gets resized the right column can move underneath the left section. But now the images on the right column are overlapping.
This is the code I used for both sections.

```html
    <div class="container">
          <!-- section on the left -->
  <section class="flex-column col-lg-6 one">
        <header class="logo">
        <img src="images/Visit_Ms_8_gray.png" alt="" width="382" height="119" />
      <h1 id="civil">Civil Rights</h1>
        </header>
       <div class="p-2">
  <h1>Play Now</h1> 
<div class="info">
                    <p style="display:inline-block;">Civil Rights Museum<br><span class="subtext">Jackson</span></p>
                <button class="button" style="display:inline-block; ">Get Tickets</button>
    </div>
                    

 <iframe width="560" height="294" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9zrFH-hWaXA" style="background-image:url(images/video_b.jpg)" >
    </iframe>
   </div>

 
<div class="col-lg-6">
                    <p class="subcopy">Concert Schedule at the Historic Alamo <span class="subtext">Jackson</span></p>

 <img src="images/img1.jpg">
    </div>
                                                
         <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <p class="subcopy">Cleveland Buckner Art Show at JSU <span class="subtext">Jackson</span></p>

 <img src="images/img2.jpg">
   
   </div>

    <div class="col-lg-12">
     <div class="book"><button class="button2">Book Now</button><p>Westin Downtown Jackson</p> </div>
     <div class="book"><button class="button2">Book Now</button><p>Hotel King Edward</p></div>
     <div class="book"><button class="button2"> Listen  </button><p>Roadtrip Playlist on Spotify
</p></div>
          </div>
        </section>
   
   
   
   
   <!-- section on the right -->
  <section class="flex-column col-lg-6 two"> 
              <header align="right">
        <h1>Play More</h1>
        <img src="images/arrow.png" />
              </header>
         
    <div class="p-2">
    <div class="flex-item col-lg-6" >
                <h1 id="later">Play Later</h1>
<div class="infob">
                    <p style="margin-bottom: 16px;">Mississippi Freedom Trail <span class="subtext">Multiple</span></p>
     <img src="images/img3.jpg">
    </div>
     
    </div>

       
                        <div class="flex-item col-lg-6">
                <h1 id="laterb">.</h1>
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46837049/edit#<div class="infob" >
                    <p style="margin-bottom: 16px;">Mississippi Freedom Trail <span class="subtext">Multiple</span></p>
     <img src="images/img4.jpg">
     
    </div>
            </div>
         </div>

      <div class="flex-item">
                        <p class="subcopy">Bestonia Blues Festival <br> <span class="subtext">Bestonia</span><br></p>

 <img src="images/img5.jpg" width="560px" height="294">
   </div>
       <div class="flex-item">
      <p id="insta_text">Instagram Freed</p>
     <img src="images/instrampic.jpg"/>
    </div>
   
     </section>
          
</div>
```

http://rameyagency.com/clients/tourism/landingpg/version2/index.html
Some of the images overlap.

It was recommended I use flexbox and divide the sections into two.

Comment: You need to read http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/ to understand how bootstrap layouts work. Then after you understand how it works, Edit your post and ask an actual question, tell us what you've tried,  and consider posting some relevant code.

Comment: I was given a few days to come up with a landing page, so I picked bootstrap and I have been trying to build the site. I'm using flex-column and divided the page into two sections so that when the page gets resized the right column can move underneath the left section. But now the images on the right column are overlapping.

Answer (score -1):

While I haven't played with the new version of Bootstrap (which introduces "flexbox"), I did notice that you are placing a number of flex-items in your right-side flex-column, and your images within them. This is probably what's causing your images to overlap, as you're not arranging the flex-items in a column/row manner. This makes their container to think of them as equal, and place them together, one on top of the other in this case.

I'd suggest taking a look at implementing a grid system on your larger flex-column. This would allow you to order things around in rows and columns, and place your images in the resulting grid as needed.

Have a look over [here](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/). There are multiple options and ways to arrange your own unique grid. I'm sure one of them will fit your bill.

Good luck!